# conflict between JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i have a problem in the conflict between the JavaScript files in the my project clearly the problem is as follows

In my admin panel all users are showing on a Bootstrap table where I can sort it. There are also a pagination system. Looks Good.

I want a system => Make the full row as a button and after click on the row it's should be show a collapse hidden information "bellow the each row" where I will put users information.

i'm using sb admin v2 [link](http://startbootstrap.com/sb-admin-v2)
and 
this code will add to table file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            /*
             * Initialse DataTables, with no sorting on the 'details' column
             */
            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                "aoColumnDefs" : [{
                    "bSortable" : false,
                    "aTargets" : [0]
                }],
                "aaSorting" : [[1, 'asc']]
            });
            $('#example tbody td ').live('click', function() {
                var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
                if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {
                    /* This row is already open - close it */
                    this.src = "../examples_support/details_open.png";
                    oTable.fnClose(nTr);
                } else {
                    /* Open this row */
                    this.src = "../examples_support/details_close.png";
                    oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem?  When you do what, you see what?  Are there errors in the debug console?

Comment: when i add this code to table the first page from table work correctly but other don't work

Comment: Did you get any error in console.

Comment: Do you know that `.live()` has been removed from recent versions of jQuery?

Comment: Did you call the script in all pages or make a script in separate page and to include the script file in all pages?

Comment: yes, i'm using  `.click `

Comment: you can download this file and try it [link](https://www.mediafire.com/?ft4d4l2ffnp41t7)

Comment: the script in all page but the collapse script in the table page only

Comment: Have you check my answer?

Comment: it's not work, please  check my file uploaded to [link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ft4d4l2ffnp41t7/my_work.rar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the below code in every datatable called in pages.

```
$('#example tbody td ').live('click', function() {
                var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
                if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {
                    /* This row is already open - close it */
                    this.src = "../examples_support/details_open.png";
                    oTable.fnClose(nTr);
                } else {
                    /* Open this row */
                    this.src = "../examples_support/details_close.png";
                    oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details');
                }
            });
```

For Ex:

```
<table id="example">
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
 $('#example tbody td ').live('click', function() {
                    var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
                    if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {
                        /* This row is already open - close it */
                        this.src = "../examples_support/details_open.png";
                        oTable.fnClose(nTr);
                    } else {
                        /* Open this row */
                        this.src = "../examples_support/details_close.png";
                        oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details');
                    }
                });
</script>
```

or using on instead of live.

Thanks.